# Encrypt an id in Rails URL and access it on separate Front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have a Rails API with minimal authentication - just a simple bearer token hooked up to Auth0.

I have one endpoint which looks like this:-

```
mysite.com/api/users/1/calendar.ics
```

The URL is unauthenticated, to allow people to subscribe to their calendars.

I'm basically trying to hide the id, and change it to a SecureRandom hex or something, so that other users can't just change the id and see other individuals' calendars.

How would I achieve this?

My front end would need some way of knowing what the encrypted string was - and since we only have bearer token auth, I'm not sure if it's secure enough to just pass the calendar URL into authenticated requests to `users/1`, for example:-

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "intro": "string",
    "calendar_url": "mysite.com/api/users/jUhGtDhajaluyt34/calendar.ics"
    "created_at": "2021-05-13T16:15:09.748Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-13T16:15:09.748Z"
  }
```

Is delivery of the URL like this even a valid concern?

Comment: how about friendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id, which you can do like this: `@user.friendly.find SecureRandom.hex(6); redirect_to @user;`, the URL will be `/users/{hex}`

Comment: @LamPhan - would that not mean all ids in User routes are replaced with friendly id then?  I only want this to happen on one User route.

Comment: it's not replace any route, that gem create an extra data table to map friendly url to normal url.